# Can we create more than 1 instance using Private Constructor?

Tags: c#, private-constructor

We all know that we cannot create object of class having private constructor. So the question arises is how many instances of this class can be created .Please find a sample code below.

```
public class Test
{
    public int val ;
    private Test(int sent)
    {
        val=val +sent;
    }
    public static void Callme(int  GetVal)
    {
        Test obj=new Test(GetVal);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.val);
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        Test.Callme(10);
        //Console.WriteLine(Test.val);
        Test.Callme(20);
        //Console.WriteLine(Test.val);
    }
}
```

As per what I know It should create 2 object of the class. Need help understanding this.

Comment: Although the constructor is private, method `Callme` acts as a static factory (although doesn't return the instance). So you can create as many instances as you like through your factory.

Comment: the access modifier of a constructor has nothing to do with how many instances you can create. `private` here only means that only members of `Test` can access the constructor (and create instances). So yes, in your example two different instances are created.

Answer (score 4):

> We all know that we cannot create object of class having private constructor.

Well, that's not accurate. You can create an object (instance) of a class having only private constructors by using static members of that class, just like in the code in the question.
What you can't do is create an instances of that class from anywhere else in the code.

> how many instances of this class can be created

In your code sample there are two instances of class `Test`.

I think what might be confusing you is you expected the second `Console.WriteLine` to print `30`, but it printed `20`. That is because `public int val ;` is an instance member. If it was a static member, than it would have printed `30`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for:

```
public static Test Callme(int GetVal)
{
    Test obj = new Test(GetVal);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.val);
    return obj;
}
```

And then create new instances like:

```
Test test1 = Test.Callme(10);
Test test2 = Test.Callme(20);
```

This way you can easily access the members of each instance. E.g. test1.val

Answer (score 0):

`Callme` method is a static method. Static methods does not require an objects instance to be called upon. They don't have the this (keyword) reference and can be called directly on the class. In your situation `Test.CallMe(someValue)`. Note that there is no object instance involved here. 
If `CallMe` was NOT a static method you would have needed an instance/object to call it. For example

```
Test ob = new Test();
ob.CallMe(someValue);
```

What your example illustrates is the use of private fields/methods.
When a method like the constructor or a filed is marked with the private keyword that method/field can only be called/accessed from within the declaring class.

This means that `CallMe` can access the constructor because `CallMe` is a member of the class and the constructor is a member of the class thus they both can access each other.

When a class has only one constructor and that constructor is private it effectively means that an instance of the class can only be created from within the class.

So in current example `CallMe` creates an instance of the class each time it's called.
If you call `CallMe` 2 times you'll create 2 instances of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Because the method Callme is static it is instantiated by the system at some point before it is used and then remains in memory for future calls. There is only one copy of a static memeber of a class ever created regardless of how many instances of the class are created.